# Unsuccessful Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape http://investopedia.com/simulator/portfolio/, but I need to make python log in to the website first. I used the requests module to do this, but it returns `status_code = 400` not 200. What should I do?

```
import requests
s=requests.session()
payload = {
    'username' : 'my email',
    'password' : 'my password'
}
response = s.post('https://www.investopedia.com/auth/realms/investopedia/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=bUGi-Bcd5XzAILUZ9PLR5pdRfkNitYSZQfokrlmRSfg&execution=4bd415ae-e295-49aa-bb7e-6b1d31d1d462&client_id=inv-simulator&tab_id=r85fhRCUBeo', data=payload)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Does it use Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create session
session = requests.Session()

url = 'http://investopedia.com/simulator/portfolio/'

payload = {
    'username': 'your_email',
    'password': 'your_password'
}

# get log in page
auth_page = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(auth_page.content, 'html.parser')

# get form
form = soup.find('form')

# get post url
post_url = form['action']

# auth
auth = session.post(post_url, data=payload)
print(auth.status_code)
```

```
200
```

P.S. please mark answer as correct if I help you

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Can you please explain in depth what you did? I'm kind of a newbie to python.

Comment: You need to generate session token. That token unique every time page login load. So you need to load that page. Get link to login (with session token) and make post request)

Comment: Can you please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484637/web-scraping-after-login/68484949#68484949? I believe it's related to this questioin.

Comment: @bassel2777 check my answer please)